# why did nodejs request POST giving 400 status code and not posting data

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to make a post request to my php code to get some data posted from nodejs but when i try to access the php file it works fine but in nodejs output it gives error to me and not posting data.

**My nodejs**

```
const request = require('request');
const notification_options = {
    url: 'https://my-site.com/site/push',
    json: true,
    body: {
       var1:"test1",
       var2:"test2"
    }
};

request.post(notification_options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(body);
});
```

PHP Code (https://my-site.com/site/push) :

```
public function actionPush(){

     var_dump($_POST);
     
        
        
    }
```

Output :

```
Status code : 400
```

when I access my php file directly from my browser it works and it returns an empty array.

How i can solve this, i need data to be posted into my php and there i want to read them.
Thanks

Comment: Where does the message `Status code:` come from? Your JavaScript prints just `Status:`

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/request/request it says it's deprecated.

Comment: The `body:` option should be a string, not an object. Use `form:`.

Comment: yes status code comes and my website source code also printing there with error

Comment: just replace body with form ?

Comment: Yes. The request library will automatically convert that to URL-encoded parameters.

Comment: i did that but still same

Comment: i tried request.get in nodejs and var_dump($_GET) in php but returns empty array from php but no errors.

Comment: Try without the `json: true` option. PHP doesn't accept JSON parameters automatically for `$_POST`.

Comment: yes i did without json: true,  same error

Comment: Maybe there's information in your server error log.

Comment: is there any way to do this ?, i need only post to my php from nodejs file

Comment: As I mentioned, you're using an obsolete library. I suggest you switch to something supported, like Axios.

Comment: As for 10 June 2017, axios library does not support posting form data in Node.js. Here is the issue on GitHub - https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/789

Comment: That's `FormData` objects that are used for file uploads. You can still use it to post ordinary forms.

Comment: it worked with request. the problem was my controller has CSRF token enabled.

Comment: You say when you run the url in the browser it work . This mean that it is get method and in node you call using post method